Linq to Entity query is taking long time to execute
I am new to linq query my linq query shown below taking long time to execute,
List<InventoyModel> vehic = new List<InventoyModel>();

vehic = Winv.Select(x => new InventoyModel
{
    InvID = x.Id,
    WeaponBrand = WH.LKP_WeaponBrand.Where(b => b.BrandID == x.WeaponBrand).Select(b => b.BrandName).FirstOrDefault(),
    LKP_WeaponBrand = x.WeaponBrand,
    weaponModel = WH.LKP_WeaponModel.Where(m => m.ModelID == x.weaponModel).Select(b => b.ModelName).FirstOrDefault(),
    LKP_WeaponModel = x.weaponModel,
    WeaponType = WH.LKP_WeaponType.Where(b => b.TypeID == x.WeaponType).Select(b => b.WeaponName).FirstOrDefault(),
    EntityCategoryID = x.EntityCategoryID,
    // LKP_WeaponType=x.WeaponType,
    SerialNo = x.Serial,
    //LKP_WeaponSerial=x.Serial,
    MadeOf = WH.LKP_BrandOrigin.Where(b => b.ID == x.MadeOf).Select(b => b.CountryName).FirstOrDefault(),
    // LKP_BrandOrigin=Convert.ToInt32(x.MadeOf),
    BulletCount = x.BuletCount,
    AssignerCategoryID = x.AssignerCategoryID,
    WeaponNote = x.Note,
    EntityType = x.EntityType,
    AssignedBy = x.AssignedBy,
    EntityStatusName = WH.LKP_EntityStatus.Where(l => l.StatusID == x.EntityStatus).Select(l => l.Status).FirstOrDefault(),
    IsFile = x.IsFile,
    MarkazName = x.MarkazName,
    MahafzaName = x.MahafzaName,
    NID = x.EmpId.ToString().Trim(),
    Datetime = x.Date,
    UpdateDate = x.ModifyDate,
    ModifierName = x.ModifyBy,
    EntityQty = x.WeaponQty,
    SCEntityQty = 0
}).ToList();

I know actually i am using many query inside query to get values creating problem but i dont know how to solve it.
Hopes for your suggestion
thanks

Have you tried benchmarking your database queries? Why not make use of navigation properties rather than having what appear to be repeat calls to the database inside your select?

@Peppermintology, if you look at query closer, you will see that there are is no repeats. Each subquery has own unique filter.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - the filters may be unique but they are repeat calls to the database as single queries which will incur a performance hit. The use of navigation properties and relationships could mitigate some of that performance by loading them via the database.

Well, good catch, probably we can remove OUTER APPLY. Looks like subqueries uses PK for join.

Can you create navigation properties to these entities? Otherwise query should be modified to use several LEFT JOIN.

The question is: what is x? Where does it come from? I bet you can adapt the code that creates x to create an InventoyModel (missing "r"?) ) directly.

More is missing: what is Winv, WH. LKP_WeaponBrand, etc. Also, is this EF, or EF-core? If the latter, please use the [entity-framework-core] tag + the appropriate [ef-core-xx] tag for the version.

What you want to do is learn to make foreign keys and point to this, then e.g. WeaponBrand would be dotted like: x.WeaponBrand.Brandname. All would then happen in 1 query with correct joins, instead of 10 queries per row.

What exactly is the goal you want to achieve with your query? Do you want to filter 1 entry where specific requirements are met? Please specify a bit more.

Your original query produces 5 OUTER APPLY queries, which is not effective. Since it looks like it is joining on primary keys, we can replace them with LEFT JOINs.
var query = 
    from x in Winv
    from wb in WH.LKP_WeaponBrand.Where(wb => wb.BrandID == x.WeaponBrand).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from wm in WH.LKP_WeaponModel.Where(wm => wm.ModelID == x.weaponModel).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from wt in WH.LKP_WeaponType.Where(wt => wt.TypeID == x.WeaponType).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from bo in WH.LKP_BrandOrigin.Where(bo => bo.ID == x.MadeOf).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from es in WH.LKP_EntityStatus.Where(es => es.StatusID == x.EntityStatus).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new InventoyModel
    {
        InvID = x.Id,
        WeaponBrand = wb.BrandName,
        LKP_WeaponBrand = x.WeaponBrand,
        weaponModel = wm.ModelName,
        LKP_WeaponModel = x.weaponModel,
        WeaponType = wt.WeaponName,
        EntityCategoryID = x.EntityCategoryID,
        // LKP_WeaponType=x.WeaponType,
        SerialNo = x.Serial,
        //LKP_WeaponSerial=x.Serial,
        MadeOf = bo.CountryName,
        // LKP_BrandOrigin=Convert.ToInt32(x.MadeOf),
        BulletCount = x.BuletCount,
        AssignerCategoryID = x.AssignerCategoryID,
        WeaponNote = x.Note,
        EntityType = x.EntityType,
        AssignedBy = x.AssignedBy,
        EntityStatusName = es.Status,
        IsFile = x.IsFile,
        MarkazName = x.MarkazName,
        MahafzaName = x.MahafzaName,
        NID = x.EmpId.ToString().Trim(),
        Datetime = x.Date,
        UpdateDate = x.ModifyDate,
        ModifierName = x.ModifyBy,
        EntityQty = x.WeaponQty,
        SCEntityQty = 0
    };

var vehic = query.ToList();

Consider introducing navigation properties in your model classes. This will simplify the query and eliminate the need for joins. With the appropriate navigation properties, your query can be simplified:
var query = Winv
    .Select(x => new InventoyModel
    {
        InvID = x.Id,
        WeaponBrand = x.Brand.BrandName,
        LKP_WeaponBrand = x.WeaponBrand,
        weaponModel = x.Model.ModelName,
        LKP_WeaponModel = x.weaponModel,
        WeaponType = x.Weapon.WeaponName,
        EntityCategoryID = x.EntityCategoryID,
        // LKP_WeaponType=x.WeaponType,
        SerialNo = x.Serial,
        //LKP_WeaponSerial=x.Serial,
        MadeOf = x.MadeOfOrigin.CountryName,
        // LKP_BrandOrigin=Convert.ToInt32(x.MadeOf),
        BulletCount = x.BuletCount,
        AssignerCategoryID = x.AssignerCategoryID,
        WeaponNote = x.Note,
        EntityType = x.EntityType,
        AssignedBy = x.AssignedBy,
        EntityStatusName = x.EntityStatus.Status,
        IsFile = x.IsFile,
        MarkazName = x.MarkazName,
        MahafzaName = x.MahafzaName,
        NID = x.EmpId.ToString().Trim(),
        Datetime = x.Date,
        UpdateDate = x.ModifyDate,
        ModifierName = x.ModifyBy,
        EntityQty = x.WeaponQty,
        SCEntityQty = 0
    });

var vehic = query.ToList();

